# Why the echo doesn't reset when I reload the browser?

Tags: php

I am new here and I'm learning PHP recently. I'm using the xampp server.
So the problem is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //this is from input type submit
        echo "it works";
    }
?>
```

So, when I click submit then it shows "it works". but when I reload the browser it does not go away.[Here the text above form does go away when I reload the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42B8j.png)

Comment: If you click refresh after a post then the browser usually tries to do another post request (i.e. repeating / reloading the request which just happened). Most browsers usually warn you about this too

Comment: Thing with php is that you've to redirect your user when it clicks on submit. you're not redirecting it to anywhere.
Edit: You can use the header function as described in php documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @HassaanAli it's not obligatory to redirect the user, you don't have to. Many people view it as good practice, but there are situations when you might not want to. You're right though that it can avoid users running into the stated problem.

Comment: Yes but in his case don't you think this method  can  avoid users running into the stated problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal.

When you submit your form, it show "It works", but when you reload the page, usually, your browser ask you if you want resend or reuse the same parameters (because the browser reuse the exact HTTP request, so resubmit the form)

Click on the URL, and press Enter to reload the page and not resend the. same request, which is a little bit different